# Reporting AIC values for model fits with multiple runs - report the min or the average?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, references, modeling, aic, reporting

I have a model that I fit with NLL minimization.
I fit that model n times with random starting values, to try to avoid local minima.

When reporting the results, it seems reasonable to *me* to report the lowest AIC value (since this most likely represents the best estimate of the true parameters), but a collaborator thinks that we should report the average AIC value and a summary of the variability of the AIC values.

What is standard practice?
(links to papers showing examples of how this is reported - very welcome!)